# awk scientific notation input

Tags: awk, scientific-notation

I'm having a bit of trouble with getting awk to read scientific notation from a file, here is some example input:

```
  #Plane   Turn   Real    Imaginary
  HOR    1    0.0000e+00    -2.1885e-07
  HOR    1    4.8481e-08    -8.1221e-08
  HOR    1    4.0934e-08    -6.0784e-08
  HOR    1    3.5707e-08    -5.1223e-08
  HOR    1    3.1664e-08    -4.5608e-08
  HOR    1    2.8268e-08    -4.1964e-08
  HOR    1    2.5242e-08    -3.9469e-08
  HOR    1    2.2429e-08    -3.7707e-08
  HOR    1    1.9731e-08    -3.6430e-08
  HOR    1    1.7082e-08    -3.5479e-08
```

I'm using awk to format this file for plotting with gnuplot using the following command:

```
gnuplot "awk '{if($2==1){printf "%.4e\n",sqrt($3^2+$4^2)}}' bathtub_values.dat" w l
```

However the arithmetic is not working correctly and after a few tests I realized that awk doesn't seem to correctly interpret the input format, how can I specify to awk the format to use?

Comment: My awk seems to work fine. Which one are you using? What results do you get? What happens if you just do `awk '{print $3*10}' file`

Comment: I get integers like:
0
0
40
40
30
30
20
20
20
10
10
10
10
90
60
30
50. I'm on Mac OS X mavericks

Comment: awk version is 20070501

Comment: The OSX version of `awk` doesn't work for me either. I suggest you install the GNU version. I am on OSX too and I use `homebrew` - it just works. I would suggest you install `homebrew` and then use that to install `gawk`.

Comment: Go here http://brew.sh and install homebrew. Then do `brew install gawk` and you are done.

Comment: I have that version of awk in Snow Leopard and your awk works correctly for me with a copy/paste of the provided inputs: `2.1885e-07\n9.4590e-08\n7.3282e-08...`.  You could try playing around with `CONVFMT` and `OFMT` (`man awk`) as well as checking your input file for strange chars (`cat -vte <filename>`)

Answer (score 3):

If you're not entitled to install a different awk, you can define and
use a function to parse the engineering notation

```
% awk 'function parse_en(eng_num) {
        split(eng_num,en,/[eEdD]/); return en[1]*10**en[2]; }
     $1 !~ /#/ {
        printf "%.4e\n",sqrt(parse_en($3)^2+parse_en($4)^2)}
'  bathtub_values.dat
2.1885e-07
9.4590e-08
7.3282e-08
6.2440e-08
5.5522e-08
5.0597e-08
4.6850e-08
4.3873e-08
4.1430e-08
3.9377e-08
%
```