# Print numbers that are in scientific notation

Tags: linux, awk, sed

I try to concatenate all numbers that are in scientific notation from file into one line.
Input (test_sc.txt)

```
A B C 1e+03 1e-03 3.39e+03
G H february
E 2.834967e+02 798
j 0.000000e+00
```

Desired output:

```
1e+03 1e-03 3.39e+03 2.834967e+02 0.000000e+00
```

Current awk command:

```
awk 'BEGIN {k=""}; {for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) {if ($i ~ (/e-/ || /e\+/)) {k=k$i" ";}}}; END {print k}' "test_sc.txt"
```

Current output:

```
1e+03 1e-03
```

Ok, if I change pattern to `/e/` it works, but prints `february` too.

if I add `print $i` to `awk` command, all numbers are printed correctly. However, as I can understand, `awk` changes the notation internally when working with numbers. How do I stop this?

`gawk 4.0` (linux), [something similar is described here,](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24517880/awk-scientific-notation-input) but they didn't explain the behaviour and recommended to change `awk`

It seems, the task is solved easier when dealing with strings, not numbers.  I'll try `sed`, if it complicated with `awk`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the following approach: *iterating through all fields and check if a field
matches specific regexp pattern for numbers in scientific notation* `/([0-9]+\.)?[0-9]+e[+-][0-9]+/`

```
awk '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){ if($i~/^([0-9]+\.)?[0-9]+e[+-][0-9]+$/){ print $i} }}' test_sc.txt
```

The output:

```
1e+03
1e-03
3.39e+03
2.834967e+02
0.000000e+00
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use `-o` option of `grep` for this then pipe into xargs to get all the results on a single line:

```
$ grep -Eo '\S+e[-+]\S+' file | xargs 
1e+03 1e-03 3.39e+03 2.834967e+02 0.000000e+00
```

Comment: Thanks, that's nice!

Comment: `echo 'me+you' | grep -Eo '\S+e[-+]\S+'` would output `me+you`. Your regexp needs to be more strict to avoid false matches.

Comment: @EdMorton it would indeed, the OP can tighten the matching constraints as necessary, I only wanted to convey the use of `grep -o` and `xargs` for this kind of problem.

Answer (score 1):

With GNU awk for multi-char RS and if you don't care about a blank char at the end and no terminating newline:

```
$ awk -v RS='\\s' -v ORS=' ' '$0==($0+0) && /e/' file
1e+03 1e-03 3.39e+03 2.834967e+02 0.000000e+00
```

The above just tests if each value is a number (i.e. it equals itself plus zero) and contains an `e` and if so prints it. If you do want to remove the trailing blank char and add a terminating newline you can massage to:

```
$ awk -v RS='\\s' '$0==($0+0) && /e/{s = (s=="" ? "" : s OFS) $0} END{print s}' file
1e+03 1e-03 3.39e+03 2.834967e+02 0.000000e+00
```

Comment: `0.100e100` is a legit IEEE float string. it normalizes to `1e99` (Try it in Perl, Python, anything else that uses the underlying `atof`

Answer (score 0):

Something was wrong with two patterns within one pair of parentheses. This works:

```
awk 'BEGIN {k=""}; {for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) {if (($i ~ /e-/) || ($i ~ /e\+/)) {k=k$i" ";}}}; END {print k}' "test_sc.txt"
```

Improvement, like suggested by @iiSeymour in the comment:

```
awk '{for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) if ($i~/e[-+]/){k=(k?k OFS $i:$i)}}END{print k}'
```

Comment: You can avoid the logical OR and the double regex match by using a character class `[+-]` and making use of the ternary operator avoids the trailing space  `awk '{for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) if ($i~/e[-+]/){k=(k?k OFS $i:$i)}}END{print k}'`

Comment: That would think a lot of strings were numbers in scientific notation when they aren't. Your regexp would need a lot of work, look at the other answers instead.

Answer (score 0):

You can use awk to test if the field can be converted to a number and then just test for an `e` or `E` in the field:

```
$ awk '{ for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) if ($i+0==$i && $i ~ /e|E/) s=s $i FS} 
       END { if (s) print s }' /tmp/file
1e+03 1e-03 3.39e+03 2.834967e+02 0.000000e+00
```

Or, to avoid the END block:

```
$ awk -v ORS=' ' '{ for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) if ($i+0==$i && $i ~ /e|E/) print $i}' /tmp/file
1e+03 1e-03 3.39e+03 2.834967e+02 0.000000e+00
```